# Griffon & Gsql plugin error

Tags: griffon

I am new to griffon, and am trying to get somethings working on it. When I run the command install-plugin gsql, 
and then run-app or test-app, my griffon application, 
I get noClassDefFoundError "Lgriffon/Core/GriffonApplication". 
The error occurs only after I install the plugin.
I have no idea why is it there. 
Any help appreciated, thanx

Comment: What Version of Griffon are you using ? I created a sample application with version 0.9 and installed Gsql Plugin for the app. Now, running the app throws error due to missing schema files etc, but the app still works.

Comment: Is the error still happening? There have been several updates to the GSQL plugin since this question was asked.